# Selected column of first row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called `data` from which I just need the first row of the column `A` and `B`.

I did `data.loc[0,[data['A'],data['B']]])` but gives the error-`None of ......are in the [ndex]`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `data.loc[0,['A', 'B']]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list of column names for default `RangeIndex` with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), first value of index in `0`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,5,4],
                     'B':[7,2,3],
                     'C':[1,1,0],
                     'D':[5,3,6],
                     'E':list('fgh')})

print (data)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  4  7  1  5  f
1  5  2  1  3  g
2  4  3  0  6  h

s = data.loc[0,['A','B']]
print (s)
A    4
B    7
Name: 0, dtype: object

a = data.loc[0,'A']
print (a)
4
b = data.loc[0,'B']
print (b)
7
```

For not default unique `Index`es is possible select first value by indexing with `df.index[0]`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,5,4],
                     'B':[7,2,3],
                     'C':[1,1,0],
                     'D':[5,3,6],
                     'E':list('fgh')}, index=list('abc'))

print (data)
   A  B  C  D  E
a  4  7  1  5  f
b  5  2  1  3  g
c  4  3  0  6  h

s = data.loc[data.index[0],['A','B']]
print (s)
A    4
B    7
Name: a, dtype: object

a = data.loc[data.index[0],'A']
print (a)
4
b = data.loc[data.index[0],'B']
print (b)
7
```

For not unique `Index`es values select by positions by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) or by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,5,4],
                     'B':[7,2,3],
                     'C':[1,1,0],
                     'D':[5,3,6],
                     'E':list('fgh')}, index=[0,0,0])

print (data)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  4  7  1  5  f
0  5  2  1  3  g
0  4  3  0  6  h

s = data.iloc[0, data.columns.get_indexer(['A','B'])]
print (s)
A    4
B    7
Name: 0, dtype: object

a = data.iloc[0, data.columns.get_loc('A')]
print (a)
4

b = data.iloc[0, data.columns.get_loc('B')]
print (b)
7
```

Comment: and how to store the two values as variables a,b?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - Use `a, b = data.loc[0,['A','B']].tolist()`